# How do you rename a jni in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

If you create a C++ project in Android Studio (JNI) and then attempt to rename the jni from the default of native-lib.cpp to another name, the file disappears from the Android Hierarchy.  What is the proper way to refactor/rename this file?

Comment: Android Studio -> Right click on native_lib.cpp file -> Refactor -> Rename as XYZ.cpp -> File name will be renamed -> CamkeList will be updated for the updated file name. If you change the view from Android to Project Explorer, modified will be seen. If not seen, you may try File -> Invalidate cache and restart -> File should be visible now

Comment: Thanks.. that's what I thought but it does not work with the lastest AS.  If you rename/refactor the cpp disappears as des the cmakelist.  odd huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vidz answered this:

Android Studio -> Right click on native_lib.cpp file -> Refactor -> Rename as XYZ.cpp -> File name will be renamed -> CamkeList will be updated for the updated file name. If you change the view from Android to Project Explorer, modified will be seen. If not seen, you may try File -> Invalidate cache and restart -> File should be visible now – Vidz Jan 2 at 13:26